# RAILS - How to automatically reconnect to pg db

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pg

I am running my rails 4 application with Postgres db, sometime my db connection getting lost with the below exception

```
 PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

And the connection is resuming properly after I restart the application, is their anyway to automatically reconnect to active record connection?